# Linking image to javascript command - Tinder Swipe Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a uni assignment I've been using this Tinder Swipe Card code:      `      http://codepen.io/developingidea/pen/meAIn

```
<div class="buddy" style="display: block;">
   <div class="avatar"  style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; background-image:url(images/girl1.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="bio">
         <h1>Name, 28</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

I have two images "hi" and "bye" that sit below the swipe feature I would like to link to the swipe feature so when "hi" is clicked the image swipes right and when "bye" is clicked the image swipes left, however, I'm unsure as to how to do this.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything out? Could you post that code?

Comment: `<div id="button">
             <img src="images/bye.svg" alt="no" width="150px" class="bye">
                <img src="images/hi.svg" alt="yes" width="150px" class="hi">
            </div>`
I tried adding the class of '.hi' and '.bye' to the javascript but that was kind of silly the way I did it because the 'hi' and 'bye' images just swiped away...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to call the `swipeleft` or `swiperight` events when the button is pressed, leaving the existing code untouched.

e.g. Adding something along these lines:

```
$("#bye").on("click", function(){
  $(".buddy").not(".rotate-left, .rotate-right").trigger("swipeleft");
});
$("#hi").on("click", function(){
  $(".buddy").not(".rotate-left, .rotate-right").trigger("swiperight");
});
```

Edit: Since there are multiple `.buddy`'s you will need to select the current one.

Comment: Thanks! This works, however, it swipes the last image and fades through the other images as if it was the current image over the top.
I'll play around with it and I'll post the code if I fix it.
Thanks again!

Comment: @lilibet No problem, if it helped solve your problem you can selected it as the answer using the green tick next to the votes! :)

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't figure out a fix, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @lilibet Ah, it was running on all of the `buddy`s at once, I didn't realise there were multiple. The amended answer should work correctly.

Comment: You absolute bloody legend! Thank you so much!